# How to insert an array to SQLite?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I need to insert an array loaded by JSON into an SQLite database. Any help is appreciated.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                    JSONArray sites = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Sites");

                    for (int i = 0; i < sites.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = sites.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String nam = c.getString("names");
                        String loc = c.getString("location");

                        HashMap<String, String> sit = new HashMap<>();

                        sit.put("id", id);
                        sit.put("names", name);
                        sit.put("location", loc);

                        array_sites.add(sit);
```

Comment: You want to add `array_sites` in to your `SQLite Database`?

Comment: Yes, correct, I want to insert array_sites in the database (SQLite).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void addData(ArrayList<String> list){

    int size = list.size();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    try{
       for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
           ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
           cv.put(KEY_NAME, list.get(i));
           Log.d("Data Inserted ",""+ cv);
           db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
       }  
       db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("Exception>>>>", e + " ");
}
```

**Call from where you store your data**

```
addData(array_sites);
```

I suggested for `ArrayList<String>`, You can use your own `ArrayList<YourDataType>`.

Comment: Leave comment if any issue with this!